WooCommerce Rest API. Add review without auth
I am trying to create a product review using woocommerce REST API /wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews. Unfortunately only authorized user with higher role can leave review. Normally anyone can leave a review but because I am using JWT Authentication for WP-API I now cant leave a review using lower level Role.
I want it so that any user Role can add product review. Is there any ways I can make this work?
Update:
This is the response im getting when I tried to add user review
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}

Ive added tried with and without Bearer Token for the role. When Im using bearer token with an Admin level somehow it is working.

I doubt the role check is dependent on your auth method

@Rup I've updated my question with some explanation on why I think it might be caused by the role.

Yes, it's definitely a role check. I thought you meant the JWT Authentication plugin was changing the check.

Here's the permissions code: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8.7.0/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-rest-functions.php#L342 So it looks like you can only create reviews over the REST API if you have edit_product permissions, which sounds like it's not for general use. I don't see an obvious filter to change this, either here or in the actual controller, unless I suppose there's a general register_rest_route filter.

@Rup So most likely I need to edit this function to enable general use correct?

No, alas, if you edit those functions they'll get reset when the plugin updates. I don't know if there's another way to do this in the REST API or if you'd have to add your own endpoint instead. If you know of a theme that supports adding reviews over AJAX already I'd have a look at how that does it.
